# DAX - Calculate price increase with incosistent time interval

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to visualize price increase in operating cost in a diagram with month in the x-axis.

The table looks like this:
[image]

As you can see the operating cost doesn't increase every month and I want to calculate the price increase from the previous occurrence

[image]

If I use `PARALLELPERIOD(DIM_DATO[Dato],-1,MONTH` in the DAX syntax I end up with this result:

[image]

So how do I create measure that calculates the price increase with incosistent time interval?

Comment: For Jan - is it the 3459 or the  sum 6918? Your formula and graph is technically correct if you truly want to compare month over month, I mean did Feb have 0 operating cost?

Comment: For jan it is the sum 6918. And yes, Feb did have 0 operating cost, so in March there would be an increase of 2 122 (=9040-6918).

Comment: Do you want show every month on the chart or just the ones with data?

Comment: Would be nice to have a calculation for both scenarios, but most importantly a chart that visualize the price increase, which in this case would only be the months with data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Total measure if you don't have one already:

```
  Pris Total = SUM('your table'[Prix])
```

Then create this measure for the difference

```
  Pris Diff = 
    var thisMonth = FIRSTDATE('DIM_DATO'[Dato])
    var prevDateWithValue = CALCULATE(LASTDATE('Driftskostnader pr system'[Dato]), ALLSELECTED('Driftskostnader pr system'), 'Driftskostnader pr system'[Dato] < thisMonth && NOT ISBLANK('Driftskostnader pr system'[Pris])  && 'Driftskostnader pr system'[Type] in { "Ny", "Endret" } )
    var diffMonth = DATEDIFF(thisMonth, prevDateWithValue, MONTH)
    var diffPrix = [Pris Total] - CALCULATE( [Pris Total], PARALLELPERIOD(DIM_DATO[Dato], diffMonth, MONTH) )
    RETURN IF(ISBLANK([Pris Total]), BLANK(), diffPrix)
```

Finally, if you want to show months inbetween without data, create this measure:

```
  Pris Diff 0 = COALESCE([Pris Diff], 0)
```

Comment: Okay, I see there are some missing valid information I should have given you on before hand. 'Pris Total' is a SUM calculation with filter on two dimensions: Pris Total = CALCULATE([Sum pris driftskostnad per system], 'Driftskostnader pr system'[Type]="Ny" || 'Driftskostnader pr system'[Type]="Endret"). I dont think this will cause any problem. 

And I have a separate date dimension table Dim_Dato. 

Your formula only works when I use the date column from the same table, nonetheless a great formula.

Comment: I've updated the above (added the [Type] in {...} to the prevDateWithValue, 3rd line). The formula should work with Dim_Dato so long as you have a Month or Year-Month column in there and you use that in your visual, and of course a relationship between the Dim_Dato and 'Your Table'.

Comment: Strange it doesn't work with Date dimension table. I have Year-Month column in both table and a many to one relationship.

Comment: Is your relationship `'DIM_DATO'[Dato] one-to-many (1 - *) 'Your Table'[Dato]` ?

Comment: It is many-to-one (*:1)

Comment: You need to switch your relationship around. Your dim_dato is a dimension table that should be one-to-many with fact tables.

Comment: I'm trying to switch it around but it is not possible. I have unique values in the date dimension table and duplicates in the other and many-to-one is the most common relationship so why must it be the othre way around?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your previous comment. One Dim_dato to Many 'your table' is how it should be. Do you have any other slicers or filters applied?

Comment: If you look at the table there are other columns which are obfuscated. One of the columns are system, so when I filter on a specific type of system I want to see the price increase in operating cost

Comment: Apologies, I missed out `ALLSELECTED('Driftskostnader pr system')` in the `prevDateWithValue` line. Try the updated measure in the answer.